# Is there a way to force users to update my ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework

Just like the title of the post. I would like to know if there's a way to force users to update my ionic app if there's a newer version. Or at least any idea how to notify them that there's a new version of the app. My ionic cli version is 2

Comment: If you're publishing your app to playstore and appstore, you'll have to keep track of the latest app version number on your server and use an API to check whether the current version of the app is older than the latest version number received from the API.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [App Version Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version/), you're able to request the users' version of your application. Once retreived, you able to decide for yourself what to do when a version (mis)matched. For example you could open the device's application store using the [Market Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/market/).

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own design for an Ionic application.

- You can track the current version of your application and store the latest application in DB.
- Next step is to compare your current version of the app with the DB and decide what action need to be taken for an APP.

**Other solution**, you can directly use Force Update of Firebase which is a ready solution for any application.